# Paying more mana for a Flashed creature

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Flash](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFlash%5d) says

> You may put a creature card from your hand onto the battlefield. If you do, sacrifice it unless you pay its mana cost reduced by **up to** 2.

*(emphasis mine)*

Does this "up to" clause mean that I can choose to Flash something and pay its full mana cost, or that it's only reduced by one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The use of "up to" means that the discount is optional.  You can chose to have Flash's ability use a generic mana cost reduction of 0, 1, or 2.

---

## Rules justification

The phrase "up to" is consistently used in Magic to mean you get to chose a number between 0 and the full value.  You can choose to have [Abandon Reason](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAbandon%20Reason%5d) target 0, 1, or 2 creatures.

See the ruling on [Training Grounds](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTraining%20Grounds%5d) (which has a similar cost reduction) for one defense of this:

> You may choose not to apply Training Ground’s cost reduction effect. You may also choose to apply only part of it (causing an activated ability of a creature you control to cost just {1} less to activate).

As further defense, the use of "up to" is not necessary to support cards that have less than 2 generic mana in their cost.  Magic in general does not need specific wording to prevent numbers from going negative (see `107.1b Most of the time, the Magic game uses only positive numbers and zero.`).  For example, [Arcane Melee](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArcane%20Melee%5d) and [Power Artifact](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPower%20Artifact%5d) do not include the phrase "up to", and yet each reduces costs just fine.

---

## Where this matters

Where the optionality of cost reduction usually matters is with cards like [Prossh, Skyraider of Kher](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bProssh%2c%20Skyraider%20of%20Kher%5d) or [Jeleva, Nephalia's Scourge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bJeleva%2c%5d%2b%5bNephalia%27s%5d%2b%5bScourge%5d).  However, this isn't relevant here because [Flash](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFlash%5d) is not casting the creatures, and therefore not reducing the mana spent to casting them.  Mana burn was one of the main reasons this would matter; good thing Wizards got rid of that rule :)  For examples of when this would matter, see here: [When would it be advantageous not apply Training Ground's cost reduction?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/47456/9999)

Comment: @Arthur There is no mana spent to cast Prossh if you use Flash because Prossh isn't cast.  It's the same as if you had used Elvish Piper.

Comment: You can't necessarily use Arcana Melee as justification, because it reduces casting costs - the costs you pay for the Flash effect are not casting costs, so they dont necessarily use the same wording. As Glorfindel has quoted, the ruling for Flash has the example of the 1R creature that "you'll have to pay {R} to keep it".

Comment: @Hackworth I included that card-specific ruling in my answer as well as a discussion of it.

Comment: How do you explain the ruling then? If the cost reduction was optional, then why do you "have" to pay R to keep an 1R creature? Also, since mana burn has long since been removed, why was Flash not errata'd if mana burn was the only reason?

Comment: @Hackworth English is ambiguous "You have to pay {R} to keep it" could mean either "pay exactly {R}" or "pay at least {R}".  "The cost is {R}", meanwhile, is not ambiguous.

Comment: This answer appears to be correct based on a ruling on the card Training Ground. Training Ground also uses the phrase "up to" in the context of applying a cost reduction and the ruling says that you can ignore the cost reduction or use only part of it.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Great example.  I've added it to my answer

Comment: "However, this isn't relevant here because Flash is not casting the creatures, and therefore not reducing their casting cost (because there isn't one)." Those cards check the amount spent to cast them, not the casting cost.  The CMC of Prossh is always 6, regardless of how much is spent to cast it. Also "chose" -> "choose".

Comment: "English is ambiguous "You have to pay {R} to keep it" could mean either "pay exactly {R}" or "pay at least {R}"." While English is ambiguous, I don't think *MtG* is ambiguous in this situation. You can't doing anything in Magic unless there's a rule that says you can. You can't just decide to spent mana without there being something that requires you to spend mana.

Comment: @Acccumulation Magic is not ambiguous.  I have three pieces of evidence showing that the cost reduction on Flash is optional.  I mention the card specific ruling, not as piece of evidence in favor of my conclusion, but to show that it is not a piece of evidence against my conclusion.

Comment: I'm removing Flash's card specific ruling from my answer because it seems to be causing more confusion than it's clearing up.