# When would it be advantageous not apply Training Ground's cost reduction?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Training Grounds](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTraining%20Grounds%5d) has an optional cost reduction ability, as indicated by the card-specific ruling:

> You may choose not to apply Training Ground’s cost reduction effect. You may also choose to apply only part of it (causing an activated ability of a creature you control to cost just {1} less to activate).

Why is this conditional?  Training Grounds never co-existed with Mana Burn.  Are there any situations in which it would be advantageous to not apply this ability?

(This is related to [Paying more mana for a Flashed creature](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/47452/9999), but is about why you would not apply the cost reduction rather than whether or not you can.)

Comment: With spells, it could be as simple as avoiding Eidolon of the Great Revel, or Mental Misstep. With abilities, it's trickier.

Comment: Both Eidolon of the Great Revel and Mental Misstep check the (converted) mana cost. Cost reductions don't impact them at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main advantage here is in very niche cases where you have lands or other effects that add more than 1 mana and cards that care about the amount of mana in your mana pool. [Glissa Sunseeker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGlissa%20Sunseeker%5d), for example, has this ability:

> {T}: Destroy target artifact if its converted mana cost is equal to the amount of unspent mana you have.

If you have an activated ability that costs more than 1 mana and you can only activate it a limited number of times, the flexibility of Training Grounds's cost reduction gives you a wider range of amounts that you can end up with in your mana pool, giving you a wider range of targets that you can hit with that ability.

Similarly, [Omnath, Locus of Mana](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOmnath%2c%20Locus%20of%20Mana%5d) gets a power and toughness bonus based on the amount of mana in your mana pool. If you want to dodge [Legion's Judgment](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLegion%27s%5d%2b%5bJudgment%5d) while keeping it as large as possible, you have the flexibility to do so.

Answer (score 3):

You have a [Glissa Sunseeker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGlissa%20Sunseeker%5d) in play, and your opponent has an artifact with CMC {1}. You have 1 untapped [Lotus Vale](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLotus%20Vale%5d) and no other untapped lands or mana in your mana pool.

You want to activate an ability on a creature that normally costs {3} (like that on [Walking Wall](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWalking%20Wall%5d)), and you also want to use Glissa to destroy your opponent's artifact.

After getting 3 mana from Lotus Vale, you need to spend exactly 2 mana in order to have {1} remaining, so that you can destroy your opponent's artifact. So you choose to only reduce the cost if your ability by {1} instead of reducing it by {2}.

Comment: Your specific example doesn't work that well because you can just activate Glissa's ability before casting Dark Ritual. Also, with the ability on Training Grounds, you can activate that ability without casting Dark Ritual at all.

Comment: @murgatroid99 No; if you didn't use Dark Ritual, and reduced the cost by 2, then you would be left with 0 in your mana pool, not 1.

Comment: If you activate Glissa's ability before activating the other ability, it wouldn't matter how much mana you have after activating the other ability

Comment: I see what you mean, but there could be various reasons that you didn't or couldn't. Perhaps I just gave too much detail; the point really was that Glissa Sunseeker could cause it.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Updated; of course it's even more contrived now.

Comment: OK, not to say that I think it's necessary to make this example work, but now you have no blue mana to activate Azure Mage, no green mana to cast Glissa, and Glissa doesn't have haste. I don't want to steal your thunder so I won't edit this into my answer, but a simpler way of getting this is to be trying to hit a high CMC artifact and having Nykthos be your only way of getting enough mana.

Comment: lol oops, forgot to actually cast Glissa. Rolled back; I'll leave it as "there's a reason you didn't or couldn't activate Glissa before the other ability".

Comment: This works with Lotus Vale instead of Swamp + Dark Ritual

Comment: @Zags Thanks, I think that's close enough to what I was going for, so I've edited it.